# Is there a term to describe saving the input and output of a function for regression testing?

Tags: testing

Often in testing, if we have a function, for example:

```
def add_one(x):
    return x + 1
```

we'd want to prevent regressions by saving a set of input/output pairs and asserting the output remains the same for the given input (e.g. `[(1, 2), (100,101), (1000,1001)]`).

Is there a term to describe testing fixed points of a function to prevent regressions?

Comment: I would call that a *test set*, *reference set* or even *non-regression test set*.

Comment: Beware that *fixed-point of a function* has a quite different meaning in maths.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a term to describe saving the input and output of a function for regression testing?

This is usually considered *part* of regression testing, and not given a separate name. That is, regression testing is performed by (1) picking an input, (2) running the program to capture the output behavior on that input, and (3) saving the captured input and output as a unit test.

There are likely many tools that can do this process automatically, but typically in software engineering practice it is done by hand. One reason for this is so that the programmer can confirm the input/output is as intended and decide on the format of the unit test, which an automated tool might present in a more clunky way (usually as command line arguments and capturing the output to a file).

A related practice that you may be interested in is [record and replay debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_and_replay_debugging) (sometimes called RR). RR does what you're looking for -- capturing automatically the input and output and saving it to a unit test -- with an additional feature: it also captures any nondeterministic choices made by the program (including reading inputs, interaction with the filesystem, threads, etc.) to ensure that the captured trace is a deterministic representation of the program execution.

> testing fixed points of a function

A minor quibble -- the phrase "fixed points" means something else in this context: inputs where the output is the same as the output. Yves points this out also in the comments.